# Как загрузить иконку которая будет загружаться лишь при ховере?

Tags: css, вёрстка

есть иконка в svg в разных цветах, черный и белый при ховере. Таким образом при ховере загружается новая иконка. Даже учитывая что SVG весит очень мало, когда пользователь первый раз загрузил страницу и наводит, то иконка подгружается лишь тогда, таким образом, видно немного пустое пространство. Как можно загрузить иконку при загрузке все страницы, с учетом того что она используется лишь при ховере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте просто в сss менять цвет иконки при ховере, а не заменять одну иконку на другую. 
Так же в библиотеке jQuery есть фича, которая помогает делать прелоад рисунков, вод пример кода ниже. Если я правильно понял вопрос то должно помочь.

```js
jQuery.preloadImages = function()
 {
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
  {
   jQuery("<img>").attr("src", arguments[ i ]);
  }
 };

$.preloadImages("icon/icon.svg");
```

Это если вы вставляете svg через тег img

Comment: В таком случаи перед тем как показать весь HTML документ, скрипт заставит браузер загрузить в него уже иконку .svg